# knex js - column is of type timestamp but expression is of type character varying

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, knex.js

I am selecting rows from `tableA` and inserting the resulting rows into `tableB`, using `knexJS`. Both `tableA` and `tableB` have identical schemas in a `Redshift` database.

**Columns names and types**

1. `id - int`
2. `created_date - timestamp without timezone`

**Code**

```
knex(tableB)
  .insert(function() {
      this.select()
          .from(tableA)
          .whereRaw('id=?', ['12345']);
  });
```

**Error**

This code runs into the error below

```
error: column \"created_date\" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type character varying
```

How to fix this in code? Updating db connection properties would be very very difficult for many reasons.

Any leads/help/suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to do this:

```
knex('table1')
  .insert(
    knex.raw("?", [ knex('table2').where('id', '12345') ])
  );
```

outputs:

```
insert into "table1" (select * from "table2" where "id" = ?)
```

https://runkit.com/embed/k1vzjp5sdwlj